# Is it possible to perform upsert operation on UserTeritorry2Association?

Tags: upsert, territory-management

I am writing a batch class on the `UserTerritory2Association` SObject and I need to perform an upsert operation. I have tried to use insert and records are getting created but if I need to do upsert I am not sure what to use as ID based on which a record will be inserted or updated. I also tried to search for any documents on the internet but didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. As the [documentation for UserTerritory2Association](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userterritory2association.htm) states:

> ## Supported Calls
>
> ```
> create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()
> ```

As such, you can only `create()` and `delete()` these associations, and you cannot `update()` or `upsert()` them.

Probably the best way to handle this is to simply use `allOrNone=false` to ignore any errors:

```
Database.insert(newTerritoryAssignments, false);
```

Comment: So what should I do if a record needs to be updated?

Comment: @NightGuy you'd have to delete and reinsert.

Comment: Consider there are records like: User1 --> Teritorry1 and User2 --> Teritorry1. Now what if I need to update Teritorry1 to Teritorry3 for User1 then what should I do? How will my code identify that specific record? Do consider that I might need to make N number of similar update.

Comment: @NightGuy You would delete the old record, and insert the new. Don't think of it as a single operation (they are moving from Territory1 to Territory3), but as two separate actions (they are leaving Territory1 and joining Territory3).